# python order words of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help in some basic python scrips, well I want to order a prayer in words from longer to shorter length and without repeating, until then everything is fine, what happens is that I do not know how to do to order words of the same length alphabetically.

Comment: Use `sort` with multiple keys, `s = sorted(s, key = lambda x: (len(x), x[0]))`

Comment: File "test21.py", line 3
    list.sort(key = len x: (len(x), x[0])) , reverse=True)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `key = lambda`, not `len`

Comment: I don't do well, I order them well until I get to those that are the same size and those alphabetically order but the other way around, ie the word that begins with a is the last instead of the first.   https://gyazo.com/6fbd4cae7f9a1f9836e62881cf7833dd

Comment: I see your problem - it's more complicated if you want one set of key to be positive and another to be reversed, working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for a case where the 2 iterators will *not* be of the same order, you'll have to do it differently. You can consult this question [Sort by multiple keys using different orderings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476371/sort-by-multiple-keys-using-different-orderings). But since it doesn't contain what you really wanted, I'll answer it here:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = ['ddd', 'bb', 'ab', 'aa', 'cc', 'dab']
l = [sorted(list(g)) for b, g in groupby(s, key=lambda x: len(x))] 
l = [e for x in l for e in x]
>>> l
['dab', 'ddd', 'aa', 'ab', 'bb', 'cc']
```

This sort by negative order for length but positive order for words. Explanation: the first list comprehension turns the list of string into a list of list that contain sorted lists (by alphanumeric) of strings of same length. The second list comprehension unwraps the list of list into one list.