# Python: Sort list consisting of (int, string)-pairs descending by int and ascending by string?

Tags: python, string, sorting, integer

How do I sort a list consisting of (int, string)-pairs descending by int and ascending by string?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including sample input, sample output, and _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research

Comment: This question might be of help for scenarios like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476371/sort-by-multiple-keys-using-different-orderings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a custom `key` argument. In this case negating the `int` will cause a descending behavior, then leave the `str` which will cause ascending behavior. Putting them in a tuple will allow lexicographical sort behavior if the first key (`int`) is identical.

```
>>> data = [(1, 'hello'), (7, 'bar'), (4, 'foo'), (4, 'world')]
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda i: (-i[0], i[1]))
[(7, 'bar'), (4, 'foo'), (4, 'world'), (1, 'hello')]
```