# Sorting a list by date, most recent first

Tags: python, sorting

Let's say `my_list` is a list of `datetime` objects. I understand that I can sort this list with the most recent dates first with:

```
sorted(my_list, reverse=True)
```

Similarly, if I have a list of tuples `(datetime, str)`. Then I can sort this with most recent first by:

```
sorted(my_list, lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

But what if I want to sort by datetime, most recent first, and break ties by sorting the `str` "alphabetically"?

```
sorted(my_list, lambda x: x[0], x[1], reverse=True)
```

Now this will also sort the string in reverse alphabetical order. How do I fix it to do what I want?

Comment: As an aside: You really don't need the lambda functions to pull tuple entries,  python will sort by tuple index 0, then 1. However this doesn't address the ascending/descending issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort by multiple keys using different orderings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476371/sort-by-multiple-keys-using-different-orderings)

Comment: @RufusVS Good point. Consider this an over-simplified example for a situation where a lambda would be required.

Comment: @JayMody Thanks for the link. I think it doesn't answer my question because the answers attempt to be more general than the specific case I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `datetime` objects so that they sort in the order you want.  A simple subtraction will convert them to `datetime.timedelta` objects.

```
latest = max(x[0] for x in my_list) # the latest datetime in your list
my_sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (latest - x[0], x[1]))
```

Comment: Rather than waste the time finding the max time in the list, you could choose an arbitrary date.  You'd just get negative deltas for sort keys.

Comment: @RufusVS yes that is true.  And if you picked an arbitrary date far into the future, they'd all be positive but the order would be the same.  I just thought my point was easier to understand if I subtracted from something meaningful.

Comment: Makes sense. This is analogous to using `-x` as a key for sorting an int value highest to lowest.