# Datetime In Django Template

Tags: django, datetime, django-templates

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3376435/1690081)

In my template i need to make `1255992517000` to an date-time. i tried `{{note.created|date:"U"}}` and `1255992517000|date:"U"` but it didn't work. How to get it to work? From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std:templatefilter-date) one can see it should work, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the `{{ value|date }}` filter is capable of doing. It will not turn an integer into a date object, you must be passing it an existing date object.

You could write your own template filter to convert the value into a date first.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the filter `date:"U"` is telling the template to display seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

If you want to display a readable date / time, try something like:

```
{{ note.created|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

Comment: What do you get when you just use `{{ note.created }}`?

Comment: Matthew (below) is right - the date filter expects an actual date object, you're passing it an integer.  You need to change your `note.created` to be a date object, instead of just a timestamp, for the date filter to work.