# Convert DateField to unix timestamp in Django

Tags: python, django

How can I convert a `DateField()` value to unit timestamp representation in Django?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django Datefield to Unix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259219/django-datefield-to-unix-timestamp)

Comment: `DateField()` returns `datetime` regular python object, there are many solutions on the web describing how to convert python `datetime` object to unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

As the DateField() returns a native Python datetime.date instance, https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html, it will be the same as converting a datetime.date object to a unix timestamp integer.. such as:

```
import time
import django.models as models

date = models.DateField()
unix_timestamp = int(time.mktime(date.timetuple()))
```